# How to split array list string by comma(,) and display in android listview?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, split

I have an array list, in that array list have values like 3-00,4-00,5-00.these three values stored as a comma separated string in database. Now when i click list view these values display in alert's dialog list view one by one like

```
3-00
4-00
5-00
```

But, now displaying 3-00,4-00,5-00.
Give me any example snippet for display array List values in list view.

Comment: time is an array, you cannot split an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
String str="";
    String[] time = new String[timList.size()];
    time = timList.toArray(time);           
     //String[] strList = time.split(",");// here give an error at **time.split(",")**            
    for(String splstr: time )
    { 
        str=splstr.toString();
    }
```

Comment: hi, i tried this one, but string is not split,i have an array list, in that comma separated string is there,Now i want to split that string, any logic is there???